# Tell me whats wrong with my code for Anagram Substring problem

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
s='cbaebabacd'
p='abc'
l=[]
answer = list()
count = 0
l = list([s[i] for i in range(j,j+len(p))] for j in range(len(s)-len(p)+1))
for i in l:
    for j in range(len(p)):
        k=list(p)
        if i[j] in k:
            k.remove(i[j])
            if len(k)==0:
               answer.append(count)
            else:
                continue
        count += 1
        break
print(answer)
```

This code is giving "[]" as output but i think it should give "[0,6]" as output for the Anagram Substring problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem was `k=list(p)`, which should not be inside the inner loop but just before it.

```
s='cbaebabacd'
p='abc'
l=[]
answer = list()
count = 0
l = list([s[i] for i in range(j,j+len(p))] for j in range(len(s)-len(p)+1))
for i in l:
    k=list(p)
    for j in range(len(p)):
        if i[j] in k:
            k.remove(i[j])
            if len(k)==0:
               answer.append(count)
            else:
                continue
        count += 1
        break
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
[0, 6]
```